# error:'_UserObject' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python

I am building an ANN model for machine learning against a data train. when I call the model to validate the test data, an error occurs

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8,activation='tanh',input_dim = 10))

model.add(Dense(6,activation='tanh'))

model.add(Dense(4,activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, save_model, load_model

filepath = './input/saved_model'

save_model(model, filepath)

test = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

enter code here
```

when I process the code below, an error message appears

```
predictions = model.predict(test)

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-141-82c4f2e9fa53> in <module>()

----> 1 predictions = model.predict(test)

AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved this issue by using the older keras h5 format:
[h5-format](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#keras_h5_format)

Simply load and save the model with the .h5 extension:

```
model.save('model_name.h5')
loaded_model = keras.model.load_model('model_name.h5')
```

Answer (score 5):

You have saved your model using `.save_model` method of the `tensorflow.keras.models`. This by default saves it in `SavedModel` format of tensorflow.

When you load back the model using `tensorflow.keras.models.load_model` method, you can use the `predict` method of the model.

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(<saved_model_folder>)
predictions = model.predict(input_tensor)
```

But if you try to load the same model, which was saved using the `tf.keras.models.save_model`, using `tf.saved_model.load` you have to do it in this way:

```
model = tf.saved_model.load(<saved_model_folder>)
predictions = model(input_tensor) # Notice predict is not used.
```

The is written in the Note section of  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#call.

If you want inference(predict) function, you can do it as follows:

```
model_loaded = tf.keras.models.load_model(<saved_model_folder>)
DEFAULT_FUNCTION_KEY = 'serving_default'
predict_func = model_loaded.signatures[DEFAULT_FUNCTION_KEY]

for batch in predict_dataset.take(1):
    print(predict_func(batch))
```

I think you are using `keras` API to save and `saved_model` API to load the model and hence the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me this happened when I trained a network on computer1 and tried to predict using it on computer2. Might be related to differing tensorflow of h5py versions

Comment: I'm having this same problem.
I checked the versions of tensorflow, h5py and keras.  It's the same on both.  In fact the environment seems identical but the OS is different.  A model trained on my mac doesn't load on a windows machine.

Comment: @Omar Check my answer. Tensorflow models should work irrespective of the OS.