# Tensorflow 2.8 - AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm working on two computers (one at home and one at work); they both have TensorFlow 2.8.0 installed. When I train the model at home (it is tf.keras.Sequential model), save it by calling:

```
model.save(<filepath>)
```

and load it at work by calling:

```
tf.keras.models.load_model(<filepath>)
```

it fails with error:

```
AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

I've read here [error:'_UserObject' object has no attribute 'predict'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68173923/error-userobject-object-has-no-attribute-predict) that it might be because of different versions (which should not be my case) and that a possible solution is to use the Keras format (H5), but I wonder why this should be even necessary. Has anybody solved this issue using the default TF model format?

*(I did not try the H5 format because it means I will have to retrain or at least re-save all my models trained at the home office; I guess it will work, but I don't understand why the TF model format should not work.)*

**EDIT:** One of the models with which I experience this issue (though from my experience this should not play an issue):

```
layers = []
layers += [tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(training_data[0]), activation=None)]
layers += [tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()]
layers += [tf.keras.layers.Activation(activation_type)]
layers += [tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(training_data[0]) * 2, activation=None)]
layers += [tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()]
layers += [tf.keras.layers.Activation(activation_type)]
layers += [tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)]
layers += [tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(training_data[0]), activation=None)]
layers += [tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()]
layers += [tf.keras.layers.Activation(activation_type)]
layers += [tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(training_data[0] / 2), activation=None)]
layers += [tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()]
layers += [tf.keras.layers.Activation(activation_type)]
layers += [tf.keras.layers.Dense(classes_count, activation="softmax")]
model = tf.keras.Sequential(layers)
```

Comment: Could you share a standalone code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thank you.

Comment: @TFer2 From what I've tested creating any sequential model with arbitrary layers, then training, saving him as described above and then loading on the other computer is an issue. I added the model description into the post, but it does not play a role I think. Indeed using .h5 format solved the issue.

Comment: I have also come across this issue when switching to a new computer. Turns out the issues was due to line endings. Setting `git config --global core.autocrlf false` and checking out the branch I wanted again fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** Invoke the model like a function on the input tensor.

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(<saved_model_folder>)
model(input_tensor) # predit is really not defined
```

If you want inference/predict function badly, you can do it as follows:

```
loaded = tf.keras.models.load_model(<saved_model_folder>)
inference_func = model_loaded.signatures['serving_default']

for batch in dataset.take(1):
    print(inference_func(batch))
```

***Explaination:***
When you save a tensorflow Sequential model using the syntax `model.save(<filepath>)`, you are using a keras model.

This saves the model in default SavedModel format. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#how_to_save_and_load_a_model

> When saving the model and its layers, the SavedModel format stores the
> class name, call function, losses, and weights (and the config, if
> implemented). The call function defines the computation graph of the
> model/layer.
>
> In the absence of the model/layer config, the call function is used to
> create a model that exists like the original model which can be
> trained, evaluated, and used for inference.

Note the explaination in second paragraph. It says that when model config is not present, model's `call function` can be used for inference. Hmm !!!

How to invoke the `call` function of tensorflow keras model, when you have not defined it by Model subclassing? To understand this, we need to know what is the purpose of `call` method. Check the below example:

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

  def call(self, inputs):
    x = self.dense1(inputs)
    return self.dense2(x)
```

From the documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#call, we know that when we define a model by subclassing, the forward pass of model is implemented in `call`.

> This method should not be called directly. It is only meant to be
> overridden when subclassing tf.keras.Model. To call a model on an
> input, always use the **call**() method, i.e. model(inputs), which
> relies on the underlying call() method.

This forward pass is defined by stacking the layers in a Sequential keras model. Hence we can treat the sequential model itself to be the `call` function. So after loading the model, we should use it like a function which takes the input tensors.

Hence `model(input_tensor)`

Comment: Sadly, I no longer have the project to test this, but what you write seems to make sense, however without the possibility to test it, I'm reluctant to accept the answer, so I just upvoted it. If somebody will comment that it works for him I will accept your answer. Thank you for making the time to create such comprehensive answer.

Comment: @eXPRESS You can just check the documentation of tensorflow links I have mentioned. Examples are written where model is directly treated like function. Even in tensorflow object detection API examples https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_object_detection_saved_model.html#putting-everything-together, you will see the same way. `detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)`.  I just collected tensorflow documentation links to compose this answer.

Comment: I was going crazy thinking I saved my model wrong. This worked for me.