# How to Load and Use Model from Older Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm having a problem loading a Tensorflow model I downloaded. Based on the error, it sounds like incompatibility issue with model from older Tensorflow? I tried to load it on Tensorflow 2.4, 2.3 with no success. It throws a completely different error.

Inside model folder, I see checkpoint, saved_model, pipeline.config.

Inside model/saved_model folder, I see variables and saved_model.pb.

If I try to load using tf.keras.models.load_model("model/saved_model"), I get this.

```
WARNING:tensorflow:SavedModel saved prior to TF 2.5 detected when loading Keras model. Please ensure that you are saving the model with model.save() or tf.keras.models.save_model(), *NOT* tf.saved_model.save(). To confirm, there should be a file named "keras_metadata.pb" in the SavedModel directory.
ValueError: Unable to create a Keras model from SavedModel at design-system-detector/rico/models/mobilenetv2-50k/saved-model/saved_model. This SavedModel was exported with `tf.saved_model.save`, and lacks the Keras metadata file. Please save your Keras model by calling `model.save` or `tf.keras.models.save_model`.
 Note that you can still load this SavedModel with `tf.saved_model.load`.
```

If I load with tf.saved_model.load, it just returns _UserObject, and I can't run model.predict.
`AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'predict'`
What's the best way to use this model to predict?

Comment: Please try using the latest TensorFlow version. Also, Please have a look at this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72602796/tensorflow-2-8-attributeerror-userobject-object-has-no-attribute-predict) which might help you to solve this error.